# jQuery getJSON results - trying to create text <a> links from results but only getting [objectObject] in return - it works fine with image <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, getjson

I'm getting results from flickr API via jQuery getJSON, all fine there. I've got `<a>`nchors around images and these render fine.

However, I can't seem to get standard text `<a>` links working using the same method of wrapping an anchor around the result. All I'm getting is `[objectObject]`.

I'm building a result block via `append/appendTo` which is all working. I tried 2 methods of building the text `<a>` links:

1. create var with html/href-attr - reference this var in the appropriate DOM element
2. create var with html/href-attr - dynamically `appendTo` this var to the appropriate DOM element

Method 1 results in `[objectObject]` - method 2 actually inserts the links but repeats the amount of links in diminishing amounts for every cycle of the `.each()` loop, but with zero output on the last element.
(I've included method 2 in commented-out form).

So I feel that method 1 is the right direction - it renders correctly, but it needs the actual links instead of Object references.

Can anyone advise here please??? Many thanks in advance.

Here's a working [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMvQEa?editors=1010), and here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="block" class="col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.img-thumbnail{ max-height: 100px; }

(function() {

    var flickerAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";

    $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
        tags: "kittens",
        tagmode: "all",
        format: "json"
    }).done(function( data ) {

        $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {

            // block shell:
            var Outer = $('<div class="col-sm-12">');
            var Inner = $('<div class="row">').appendTo(Outer);

            // image/anchor/element:
            var Img = $('<img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">').attr('src', item.media.m);
            var ImgAnchor = $('<a>').attr('href', item.link).append(Img);
            var ImgDiv = $('<div class="col-sm-3">').append(ImgAnchor);
            ImgDiv.appendTo(Inner);

            // item links:
            var AuthorText = ("Author...");
            var AuthorAnchor = $('<a>').attr('href', item.author).append(AuthorText);
            // var AuthorAnchor = $('<a>').attr('href', item.author).append(AuthorText).appendTo('.author-wrap');

            var LinkText = ("Item...");
            var LinkAnchor = $('<a>').attr('href', item.link).append(LinkText);
            // var LinkAnchor = $('<a>').attr('href', item.link).append(LinkText).appendTo('.link-wrap');

            // build element:
            var CopyDiv = $(
                '<div class="col-sm-9">' + 
                    '<div class="row">' +
                        '<div class="col-sm-3">' + AuthorAnchor + '</div>' +
                        // '<div class="col-sm-3 author-wrap">' + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-sm-3">' + item.published + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-sm-3">' + LinkAnchor + '</div>' +
                        // '<div class="col-sm-3 link-wrap">' + '</div>' +
                    '</div>' + 
                '</div>');

            // append element to Inner:
            CopyDiv.appendTo(Inner);

            // append Outer to block:
            Outer.appendTo('#block');

            // limit output
            if ( i === 4 ) {return false;}

            // log the json data
            console.log(data);

        });

    });

})();
```

Comment: what do you want to be shown in the left [Object] and in the right [Object]?

Comment: This is the api call:
https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=kittens&tagmode=all&format=json
I am trying to create links from the object properties of: 'item.link' and 'item.author'. Instead of that value I'm just getting [objectObject].

Comment: I '.append()' those links with the visible text I want in the link (see vars AuthorText and LinkText) - but it's the href value which should be returned from the API call which I can't get working.

Comment: check this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpzxxY?editors=1010

Comment: @zb22 thanks! +1 
That works perfectly and I see the error of my ways. I'll implicitly say this is the correct answer as you got in there first but without my ability to 'tick' it. 
So I'll do that for the next answer from Mikael Lennholm but you're both right. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: It's ok, you can at least vote for my comment

Comment: Done - missed the ^ arrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this part of your code:

```
        // build element:
        var CopyDiv = $(
            '<div class="col-sm-9">' + 
                '<div class="row">' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-3">' + AuthorAnchor + '</div>' +
                    // '<div class="col-sm-3 author-wrap">' + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-3">' + item.published + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-3">' + LinkAnchor + '</div>' +
                    // '<div class="col-sm-3 link-wrap">' + '</div>' +
                '</div>' + 
            '</div>');
```

You can't append elements this way because this is just plain string concatenation, which means that the `toString()` method is implicitly invoked on `AuthorAnchor` and `LinkAnchor` since those are objects.

This part of your code needs to look something like this instead:

```
        var authorCol = $('<div class="col-sm-3"></div>');
        authorCol.append(AuthorAnchor);

        var linkCol = $('<div class="col-sm-3"></div>');
        linkCol.append(LinkAnchor);

        var row = $('<div class="row"></div>');
        row.append(authorCol);
        row.append('<div class="col-sm-3">' + item.published + '</div>');
        row.append(linkCol);

        var CopyDiv = $('<div class="col-sm-9"></div>');
        CopyDiv.append(row);
```

Note: by chaining method calls, the code I suggested can be made a lot less verbose, I wrote it this way to make it more easily understandable.

---

Another solution would be to create `AuthorAnchor` and `LinkAnchor` as HTML strings instead of DOM nodes, then the string concatenation would work fine. Keep in mind though that this is only advisable as long as you use jQuery or some other similar DOM manipulation tool.

Comment: Thanks very much for this and I've learnt from your reply @Mikael Lennholm. I've marked this as the correct answer - please also see my comment above to zb22 as that was first and also works, but both replies have helped here.

Comment: I tried your method chaining suggestion and it worked 1st time. 
My initial attempt with CopyDiv was to meant to keep the whole block in 1 variable and to avoid too much chaining, but I can see how that fails now with the other elements I'm using, plus the fiddly aspect of so much concatenation. 
Thanks again for the help.